# The shortest legal German sentence

Tags: sentence-structure, curiosity

One day a lecturer of mine stated that the shortest German sentence consists of two words. He gave examples like “Sie geht.” (she goes), “Es schreibt.” (it writes) and so on.

However, even though this was five years ago, it still bothers me. I think there is a shorter sentence possible consisting of only one word:

> Erik frage: »**Warum?**«
>   Hans antwortete: »**Darum!**«
>   Erik sagte daraufhin: »**Okay.**«

Are examples like these (“Warum?”, etc.) no sentences? So, what is really the shortest valid sentence in the German language?

Comment: All these short examples are direct speech. You could argue that a spoken sentence is a special form of sentence.

Comment: It seems to be not so much a statement about the German language or German usage as it is a (possibly somewhat idiosyncratic) definition of what counts as a “sentence”. Which does not seem like a particularly important distinction. People do utter single words like “Äh”, “Ja”, “Nö” or “Awa” in Germany like elsewhere. “Äh” is only two letters and a single phoneme.

Comment: From just the title, I was going to say "Schuldig"

Comment: For those who misread the title as I did: The absolute minimum is 1 month. Prison sentences of less than 6 months are handed out only in special circumstances.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The answer to your question depends on what a sentence is. But this is not really clear. [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satz_(Grammatik)#cite_ref-kessel-1_3-0) claims that there are about 200 different definitions of what a grammatical sentence is.

So you might find definitions that say:

> “Okay.” is a sentence, because it is a complete statement.

but you will also find definitions that say:

> No! A sentence must have a subject and a predicate which are two different words, and therefore “Okay.” is *not* a sentence.

So, if you can choose from the definitions, then take a definition that allows one-word-sentences, and then chose a two-letter-word (there are no one-letter-words in German) like »ja« and find a context that transforms this word into a sentence:

> Hast du Hunger?
>   **Ja.**

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44857/discussion-on-answer-by-hubert-scholnast-the-shortest-legal-german-sentence).

Comment: "What is the first letter of the alphabet?" "A."

Answer (score 19):

If it is about the shorteness, imperative works:

> Geh!

If number of characters matter,

> tu, üb, sä, iß (alt.)

would optimize your request (as remarked by Wrzlprmft).

Comment: Wrzlprmft himself has his name optimized for the number of characters.

Comment: The imperative is indeed the best option, as that one doesn't need a subject; I cannot imagine any reasonable definition of"sentence" to not consider "Geh!" as complete sentence. Note that before the spelling reform you could even go shorter: "Iß!" Of course now that's also three letters: "Iss!"

Answer (score 5):

Ein "Satz" ist ein theoretisches Konstrukt, das keine genaue Entsprechung in der Sprachwirklichkeit hat.

Zuerst ist da das Sprechen und Schreiben der Menschen. Diese Sprachpraxis beobachten Linguisten und versuchen, Regelhaftigkeiten zu erkennen. Den Versuch, diese Regeln, die möglicherweise die Sprachproduktion leiten, aus der Sprachpraxis abzuleiten, nennt man "Grammatik". Grammatik ist also nicht das Regelwerk einer Sprache, sondern eine Hypothese, die auf bestimmten Annahmen beruht. Eine dieser Annahmen ist der Satz.

Wie aber kommt man auf die Idee des Satzes? Die Grammatik hat sich (in der Antike) zuerst mit den Worten beschäftigt: ihrer Bedeutung, Etymologie und Morphologie. Erst ungefähr im 2. Jhdt. v. Chr. begannen die griechischen Grammatiker dann, sich mit der Syntax zu beschäftigen. "Syntax" bedeutet soviel wie "das geordnete Zusammensetzen" und untersucht, wie Worte zu sprachlichen Äußerungen zusammengesetzt und angeordnet werden.

Bei dieser Untersuchung wurden die Regeln von Subjekt, Prädikat und Objekt aufgestellt, die wir aus dem Griechisch- und Lateinunterricht kennen. Die älteste Definition eines Satzes ist also eine, die ein Subjekt und Prädikat beinhaltet. Dies liegt auch daran, dass die antiken Grammatiker ihre Theorie der Syntax in Bezug auf die philosophische Logik erstellt haben, die sich mit Aussagen und ihren Bestandteilen beschäftigt.

Späteren Syntaktikern ist dann aber bald aufgefallen, dass sprachliche Aussagen nicht unbedingt vollständige Sätze im Sinne einer Prädikatenlogik sind. Viele Sätze scheinen unvollständig oder widersprechen der Subjekt-Prädikat-Objekt-Definition. Deshalb wurde versucht, neue Definitionen zu finden, die das Konzept des Satzes erweitern, oder es wurden andere Textelemente definiert, die keine Sätze sind und neben diesen existieren (z.B. Interjektionen).

Um nach dieser ausführlichen Einleitung nun endlich auf deine Frage zu kommen, welches der kürzestmögliche deutsche Satz ist, so macht diese Frage aufgrund des hypothetischen Charakters des Konzeptes "Satz" wenig Sinn. Zum einen kommt man, je nachdem welche Definition von "Satz" man zugrunde legt, zu je unterschiedlichen Antworten. Zum anderen erfasst diese Antwort die sprachliche Wirklichkeit möglicherweise überhaupt nicht.

Eine sinnvollere Frage wäre z.B., welches die kürzest mögliche sprachliche Äußerung ist. Oder welches die kürzest mögliche Subjekt-Objekt-Konstruktion ist. Ob dies dann "Sätze" sind, ist eine Frage, für die sich im Grunde nur Linguisten interessieren und die für die Sprachpraxis ohne Bedeutung ist.

---

Die kürzestmögliche sprachliche (also bedeutsame) Äußerung ist ein einzelner Laut. Beispiele sind einzelne Phoneme:

> "Schau mal."
>   "Oh."

*Die [Interjektion "oh"](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/oh) wird zwar in der Regel nur, wenn sie in Verbindung mit anderen Wörtern vorkommt, [als einzelner Buchstabe ohne "h"](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/o_Ausruf_Freude_Schreck) geschrieben, ist aber gesprochen ein einzelner Laut.*

und phonemlose Laute:

> "Peter?"
>   "Hm?"

*Das "hm" ist hier kein Phonem [bedeutungsunterscheidende lautliche Einheit], da die Bedeutung dieser Äußerung nur von der Intonation abhängt. Sie kann sowohl mit geschlossenem ("hm?"), halb geöffnetem ("hn?"), als auch mit geöffnetem Mund (geschrieben "hä?", gesprochen "h?") gesprochen werden.*

sowie Namen von Lauten:

> "Schreibt man Käse mit e oder ä?"
>   "Ä."

Die kürzesten nach den unterschiedlichen Regeln der Syntax gebildeten Satzkonstruktionen sind in den anderen Antworten zu finden.

Answer (score 4):

The shortest sentence with subject and predicate I can think of is

> Er aß.

Comment: Oder umgangssprachlich "I seh" (Ich sehe) was nur drei Laute hat.

Comment: Using "A" as a name, "A aß".

Comment: Tu es! , could be shortened to "Tu's!"

Comment: @rackandboneman That is not subject + predicate, that is predicate + object.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if it applies to what you want to know, but there are certain sentence fragments (`Satzfragmente`), commonly used when answering to a question.

> How much is left? / Wie viel ist übrig?
>   Nothing (is left). / Nichts (ist übrig).

You're basically leaving out a part of the sentence, but from the context it's clear what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

If it is not an imperative sentence, then a grammatically complete sentence always needs at least a subject and verb that is flected to it. Nevertheless, German allows for truncated senctences. These are sentences where the missing part is assumed to be known.

> Warum?

Is a truncated sentence. Depending on the context you can complete it:

> **A:** Ich muss nach Hause gehen.
>
> **B:** Warum [musst du nach Hause gehen]?
>
> **A:** Darum [muss ich nach Hause gehen, weil es spät ist].

And, of course, *ja* and *nein* are answer particles and do not form a sentence.

> **A:** Hast du es verstanden?
>
> **B:** Ja.
>
> **A:** Hurra!

As you see with the last "sentence", this is only an interjection and hence also not a complete sentence. Nevertheless, all this is correct usage of the German language.

Answer (score 0):

You can also have sentences with only one word, where the subject is understood, but clearly defined by the predicate.

Jörgi: Mutti, ich war heute wirklich in der Schule!
Mutter: Warst?

oder

Spinnst /du/?
Spinnt /ihr/?